# What if assign static variable to local variable?

Tags: java, static-members

What happened in this case,

```
static Object MAX = 5;
    public Object tmp = 0;

    public void process() {
        tmp = MAX;
    }
```

will **tmp** also behave like class variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The references are the same, so as long as you will not change `tmp`, it will point to the value of `MAX`. If `MAX` gets a new value (without changing the reference) `tmp` will point to that same value.

However, you cannot access `tmp` without an instance.

As you assign `5` to the `MAX` object, you will end up with a `Integer`. This is Java's auto-boxing feature. `Integer` has no methods to change it's value; so you will have to reassign `MAX` to a new object if you wish to change it. Then `tmp` will no longer point to the same value, unless you call `process()` again.

Answer (score 4):

> What if assign static variable to local variable?

Both points to same reference.

> Will tmp also behave like class variable?

It is a `instance` member. So no. You have to make it as `static` to become class member.

If your just testing that is ok, But if it is a real scenario ,defenitley you need to think about your design.